# Efficient alternative to merge() when building dataframe from json files with R?

Tags: performance, json, r

I have written the following code which works, but is painfully slow once I start executing it over thousands of records:

```
require("RJSONIO")
people_data <- data.frame(person_id=numeric(0))

json_data <- fromJSON(json_file)
n_people <- length(json_data)
for(person in 1:n_people) {
        person_dataframe <- as.data.frame(t(unlist(json_data[[person]])))
        people_data <- merge(people_data, person_dataframe, all=TRUE)
    }

output_file <- paste("people_data",".csv")
write.csv(people_data, file=output_file)
```

I am attempting to build a unified data table from a series of json-formated files. The `fromJSON()` function reads in the data as lists of lists. Each element of the list is a person, which then contains a list of the attributes for that person.

For example:

```
[[1]]
    person_id
    name
    gender
    hair_color
[[2]]
    person_id
    name
    location
    gender
    height

[[...]]

structure(list(person_id = "Amy123", name = "Amy", gender = "F",
               hair_color = "brown"), 
          .Names = c("person_id", "name", "gender", "hair_color"))

structure(list(person_id = "matt53", name = "Matt", 
               location = structure(c(47231, "IN"), 
                                    .Names = c("zip_code", "state")), 
               gender = "M", height = 172), 
          .Names = c("person_id", "name", "location", "gender", "height"))
```

The end result of the code above is matrix where the columns are every person-attribute that appears in the structure above, and the rows are the relevant values for each person. As you can see though, some data is missing for some of the people, so I need to ensure those show up as `NA` and make sure things end up in the right columns. Further, `location` itself is a vector with two components: `state` and `zip_code`, meaning it needs to be flattened to `location.state` and `location.zip_code` before it can be merged with another person record; this is what I use `unlist()` for. I then keep the running master table in `people_data`.

The above code works, but do you know of a more efficient way to accomplish what I'm trying to do? It appears the `merge()` is slowing this to a crawl... I have hundreds of files with hundreds of people in each file.

Thanks!
Bryan

UPDATE:
Based on the feedback below, I tried to build a list of all the people, and then convert it all at one time into a dataframe. I let it run overnight and still didn't finish making the dataframe. There are around 1/2 million people in the list. That codes looks like this:

```
require("RJSONIO")
require("plyr")
people_data <- data.frame(person_id=numeric(0))
people_list <- list()

json_data <- fromJSON(json_file)
n_people <- length(json_data)
for(person in 1:n_people) {
        people_list[[person]] <- t(unlist(json_data[[person]]))
    }

#PROBLEM CODE, SLOW, 1/2 million records in people_list
people_data <- rbind.fill(lapply(people_list, as.data.frame))

output_file <- paste("people_data",".csv")
write.csv(people_data, file=output_file)
```

Comment: Have you profiled the code so you know that most of the time is being spent in `merge()`? It might be due to you repeatedly merging to incrementally add to `people_data`. This sort of thing in a loop in R is generally the pinch point because R has to copy, expand, assign each iteration. In general `merge()` is quick, so I suspect the problem is the incremental expansion in the loop.

Comment: I think so. Do you know of a more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

If you don't expect duplicate records to exist, you can use `rbind.fill` from the [`plyr`](http://had.co.nz/plyr/) package.

Comment: Even if there are duplicates, I think rbind.fill then unique would be faster than doing a merge over and over

Comment: Thanks Daniel, the rbind.fill works but doesn't appear terribly faster. I think the issue might be what Gavin identified above?

Comment: Two alternatives you can try that might be faster: `json_df <- lapply(json_data, as.data.frame)` Then either `do.call(rbind, json_df)` OR `Reduce(rbind, json_df)`.  But doing the as.data.frame part may be the bottleneck.

Comment: @daniel-dickinson, see my update in the original post. I think that is what I'm doing now? So you may be right its the as.data.frame.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you know all names for fields. Here is solution.

Example data

> data_list <- list(list(person_id = "Amy123", name = "Amy", gender = "F",hair_color = "brown"),
>                     list(person_id = "matt53", name = "Matt",location = list(c("zip_code"=47231,
>                          "state"="IN")),gender = "M", height =  172))

Names for example records

> nm1 <- names(unlist(data_list[[1]]))
>     nm2 <- names(unlist(data_list[[2]]))
>      nm <- c(nm2,nm1[!nm1 %in% nm2])

Code of program

```
record_template <- vector(mode="character",length=length(nm))
names(record_template) <- nm
record_template <- "NA"
rec <- function(x) {
              tmp <- record_template
              tmp[names(unlist(x))] <- unlist(x)
              return(tmp)
       }

do.call(rbind,lapply(data_list,rec))
```

## EDIT

You can get names from list using:

```
nm <- unique(unlist(lapply(data_list,function(x) names(unlist(x))),use.names=F))
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be a comment but ldply might be more efficient once you get your unlisted person objects back in a list.

For example, once you do this:

```
for(person in 1:n_people) {
    people_list[[person]] <- t(unlist(json_data[[person]]))
}
```

you can just use ldply like so:

```
people_data <- ldply(people_list,function(x) as.data.frame)
```

Now this might not be that much faster, but you can parallelize this efficiently like so:

```
people_data <- ldply(people_list,function(x) as.data.frame,.parallel=TRUE)
```

Which might give you more speed gains